# Base64 String to Json String

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I currently need to send a **PDF** file through an API by converting it to a **Base64** string. I have tested my code and realize that it cannot accept the contents in my `pdfBase64String` variable.

I tried printing the `pdfBase64String` and it does not show up anything. I tried decoding back to a pdf file and it works so the problem should lie in the String itself. Is there anyway i can solve this problem? i would still want to send it in string and the other party who receives it will decode it back to the pdf file.

```java
ByteArrayOutputStream ba = loadPdf(fileName);
String pdfBase64String = StringUtils.newStringUtf8(Base64.encodeBase64(ba.toByteArray()));
System.out.println(pdfBase64String);     //Does not show anything

ApprovalReport approvalReport = new ApprovalReport(Long.valueOf(crisisID), pdfBase64String);
URI uri = restTemplate.postForLocation(CMO_SERVICE_URI + "/approvalReport/", approvalReport, ApprovalReport.class);
```

Comment: Did you print `ba.toByteArray().length` ? What is the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Base64.encodeBase64String:

```
            String pdfBase64String = Base64.encodeBase64String(ba.toByteArray());
```

Comment: If you are trying the encoding of a byte[] for an image, this won't work for a JSON string. The resulting string is not in JSON format, so you get an error that your JSON string does not start with `{'. I looked at the encoded string and it's a massively long number starting with a `/`. Just in case others were trying to convert an image byte[] to a string for a `JSONObject` object.